# Trouble with global variable

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

When run an instance of my class as shown in the code below.I try to ues 'print importWindow.GetDataVal()' to show me the value of what was entered into the dialog but it prints nothing. How can I get it to display the necessary value?

```
import wx



class ImportDialog(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: ImportDialog.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.dataValues=''
        self.path = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", size=(175,25))
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Browse for haarcascades")
        self.button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.fetchHaarPath)
        self.ok = wx.Button(self, -1, "OK")
        self.ok.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.confirmOK)
        self.cancel = wx.Button(self, -1, "Cancel")
        self.cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CloseAll)
        self.label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Name of detect object:")
        self.name = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "")
        self.spin_ctrl_1 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, -1, "", min=0, max=100)
        self.spin_ctrl_2 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, -1, "", min=0, max=100)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: ImportDialog.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("Import Custom Haarcascade")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: ImportDialog.__do_layout

        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(3, 2, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.path, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.label_1, 0, 0, 0)


        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.name, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.spin_ctrl_1, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.spin_ctrl_2, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add((20, 20), 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.ok, 0, 0, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.cancel, 0, 0, 0)
        self.SetSizer(grid_sizer_1)
        grid_sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def fetchHaarPath(self,event):
        wildcard = "XML files (.xml)|*.xml"
        haarPicker = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file",
                               wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.OPEN)
        if haarPicker.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            #print "Haarcascade filepath:", haarPicker.GetPath()
            self.path.SetValue(haarPicker.GetPath())
            haarPath=haarPicker.GetPath()
        haarPicker.Destroy()
        self.haarPath=haarPath


    def confirmOK(self,event):
        print "Path:", self.path.GetValue()
        print "Name:", self.name.GetValue()
        print "Size:", self.spin_ctrl_1.GetValue(),"X",self.spin_ctrl_2.GetValue()


        print
        #C:\Users\Foster\Documents\Roland\ims project\haarcascades\eyeglasses.xml@@(50,50)&&eye
        #C:\Users\Foster\Documents\Roland\ims project\haarcascades\eyeglasses.xml@@(50,50)&&eye
        dataVal=""
        dataVal=str(self.path.GetValue())+"@@("+str(self.spin_ctrl_1.GetValue())+","+str(self.spin_ctrl_2.GetValue())+")&&"+str(self.name.GetValue())
        self.setDataVal(dataVal)
        #print self.GetDataVal()
        self.CloseAll(event)

    def GetDataVal(self):

        return self.dataValues

    def setDataVal(self,valueData):
        self.dataValues=valueData





    def CloseAll(self,event):

        self.Close()


# end of class ImportDialog
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    importWindow = ImportDialog(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(importWindow)
    importWindow.Show()
    print "<"
    print importWindow.GetDataVal()
    print ">"
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @SWAPYAutomation yes it prints "<"

Comment: I think @Fabian is right, try with `self.dataValues='test'` in the `init` section

Comment: it prints : < > Path: "file path" Name: "name" Size: 100 X 100

Comment: You guys are right it now prints <
test
>
Path: 
Name: 
Size: 0 X 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well technically it doesn't print "nothing", it prints an empty line to stdout.

That is because you initialize `dataValues` in `ImportDialog` with an empty string and only change that string in `confirmOK`, I guess after the user has pressed a confirmation button.

Your print statement gets executed before the user has had the chance to press that button.